# node_module directory not appeared even after npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to setup a new working directory in my local system and ran below commands in VS code terminal.

```
npm init
npm install express --save
```

But node_module package not appeared inside my working directory. It throwing some error like below.

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: connect 
ETIMEDOUT 104.16.27.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-28T17_14_18_710Z-debug-0.log
```

I have already clear cache and also set proxy to null, But nothing is helpful. same issue showing again.

Comment: Something is blocking the connection, maybe the antivirus, try to disable it and try again, another possibility is your `hosts` file is redirecting the connection to localhost or to another IP.

Comment: Hi, I have disable my antivirus but same issue showing again.